# Serve JSON to client, different project structures

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, api

Hello I have a question about how i can most effectly serve json data to a client, that is getting used in the client.

I'm using is NodeJS with express.

From my server I get json / api data from an external website, manipulate the data and want to use that data client sided.

Method 1:
I saved the manipulated JSON data in a .json file on my server.

Can I directly send the JSON data from the .json file with the client on the request?

Method 2: (called a rest api i think?)
Or do i have to put the JSON data from the .json file to another client (2). So I can acces that client (2) with the Json data from client (1) with a get request?

I have never done this before and would like to hear your suggestions

Edit:

using junvar's code, I still got some problems:

NodeJS apps file:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

// const myJson = require(<path to json>);
const myJson = fs.readFileSync("apidata.json");

console.log(myJson);

// const myHtml = require('fs').readFileSync(<path to html>);
const myHtml = fs.readFileSync("new.html");

console.log(myHtml);

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(myHtml.replace(/<JSON>/g, JSON.stringify(myJson, '', 2)));

}).listen(8900);

console.log("server is running")
```

Client/html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>Hi world, here's some JSON: <JSON>.</div>
<div>Check your console too!</div>
<script>
    console.log(<JSON>);
</script>`;

</body>
</html>
```

The server is running fine untill i try to connect to the client.
It shows that myHtml.replace isnt a function.

```
<Buffer 5b 7b 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 46 61 6e 74 6f 6d 22 2c 22 73 79 6d 62 6f 6c 22 3a 22 66 74 6d 22 2c 22 63 75 72 72 65 6e 74 5f 70 72 69 63 65 22 3a 30 ... >
<Buffer 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 3e 0d 0a 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 3c 6d 65 ... >
server is running
C:\Users\admin\WebstormProjects\expressapp\fuk.js:19
  res.end(myHtml.replace(/<JSON>/g, JSON.stringify(myJson, '', 2)));
                 ^

TypeError: myHtml.replace is not a function
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes both are possible. Method 2 would be most straightforward and the recommended approach. Method 1 is useful to avoid the additional request. Check out any express tutorial, or even any vanilla node http server tutorial since your question and the basic concepts aren't unique to express.

Comment: @junvar Thankyou for the respone. I'm already working on method 2. Most tutorial show how to send only json data to the client, this makes it that you cant put in html code.  I'm very stuck on serving the json data to the client. I'm using EJS as a global var and trying to serve json the client that way, but EJS has it flaws ex. with using <script> tags. Do you recommend any tutorial ?

Comment: I've added an example containing a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment, here's an example of both approaches that you can run locally.

Yes both are possible. Method 2 would be most straightforward and the recommended approach. Method 1 is useful to avoid the additional request. Check out any express tutorial, or even any vanilla node http server tutorial since your question and the basic concepts aren't unique to express.

```
const http = require('http');

// approach 1

// const myJson = require(<path to json>, 'utf-8');
const myJson = {x: 3, y: 5};

// const myHtml = require('fs').readFileSync(<path to html>, 'utf-8');
const myHtml = `
<div>Hi world, here's some JSON: <JSON>.</div>
<div>Check your console too!</div>
<script>
  console.log(<JSON>);
</script>`;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end(myHtml.replace(/<JSON>/g, JSON.stringify(myJson, '', 2)));
}).listen(8900);


// approach 2

// const myJson2 = require(<path to json>, 'utf-8');
const myJson2 = {x: 3, y: 5};

// const myHtml2 = require('fs').readFileSync(<path to html>, 'utf-8');
const myHtml2 = `
<div>Hi world, here's some JSON: <span id="json"></span>.</div>
<div>Check your console too!</div>
<script>
    fetch('http://localhost:8901/json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        document.getElementById('json').textContent = JSON.stringify(json);
        console.log(json);  
    });
</script>`;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/json') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(myJson2));
} else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(myHtml2);
}
}).listen(8901);
```

Comment: Thank you for putting in the effort it tried it and I still have some issue's please check my updated question for the code i used. I when I try to connect to the website. It displays: that myHtml.replace is not a function. Some other suggestions?

Comment: That's because `fs.readFileSync(path)` returns a buffer as opposed to a string. Updated my comment, it should read `fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you recieved (req, res) parameters from express into your method. Send response from your method like

```
res.json({
   key1:value1,
   key2:value2
})
```

Comment: Thank. And get the values by uisng EJS right? I tried that but I also use the values inside <script> tags and with the EJS <% %>, does go so well together. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Make api from node server,So your client can get data

Comment: so make/run a different client like https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins . Were I make a get request to?